# Android Navigation Component: How to solve the circular navigation with nested graph?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

In our user requirement we have a flow like this.

[image]

I have searched the following:

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles

[Circular Reference with Nested Nav Graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083805/circular-reference-with-nested-nav-graphs)

But nothing can help...

**What I have done?**

Currently I split 2 graph and add duplicate Fragment C in Graph2. Also, I change the graph start destination to Fragment C in graph 1 programmatically only I clicked from graph2. This is an ugly solution But I have no idea how to solve this issue.

**My question is : Is there any way to do it rather making a duplicate destination and changing the start destination?**

Graph 1:

```
<include app:graph="@navigation/graph2" />
<dialog
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:label="Fragment A"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragmentA"/>
<dialog
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        android:label="Fragment B"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragmentB">
    <action
            android:id="@+id/NavigateToGraph2"
            app:destination="@id/graph2">
</dialog>
<dialog
        android:id="@+id/fragmentC"
        android:label="Fragment C"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragmentC"/>
<dialog
        android:id="@+id/fragmentD"
        android:label="Fragment D"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragmentD"/>
<dialog
        android:id="@+id/fragmentE"
        android:label="Fragment E"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragmentE"/>
```

Graph 2

```
<dialog
        android:id="@+id/fragmentF"
        android:label="Fragment F"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragmentF"/>
<dialog
        android:id="@+id/fragmentG"
        android:label="Fragment G"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragmentG"/>
<dialog
        android:id="@+id/fragmentC"
        android:label="Fragment C"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragmentC"/>
```

Comment: I don't know if android supports this as of now, but the following might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51263301/multi-module-navigation-with-architecture-components

Comment: Thx a lot for the advice. However, the fragment C would received enum object and parcelable object from the source destination. Would it be possible to pass these 2 type by deeplink?

Comment: Which one is your start destination?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't add the start destination in graph 1. Fragment A,B,C,D,E are just the part of the whole navigation. You can assume there is a Fragment AA as the start destination in graph1. In Graph 2, Fragment F is the start destination

Comment: I would suggest you make Fragment C abstract to share your logic into inheriting fragments C1 & C2 where C1 is part of graph 1 while C2 is part of graph 2.

Comment: @JeelVankhede This could make the issue more complicated. It will create more unnecessary classes and xmls  for every circular navigation. Also, it is bad for maintainence.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to create a graph for fragment F and break the circular loop.

Comment: How does it solve the circular loop? The new created graph for fragment should also include Fragment G as the destination